# storage event is getting triggered even in current tab where it modified the localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

In my top level react component I have added Storage event handler to reload my application on another tab when ever there is change in the localstorage value.

it is working fine it is triggering the storage event handler in all other tabs,

but it is also triggering this event in the same current tab where localstorage got changed on click of a button.

```
useEffect(() => {

const onStorageValueChnage = event => {
  const { key } = event;

  if (key ==='token') {
    window.location.reload();
  }
};

window.addEventListener('storage', onStorageValueChnage);
return () => {
  window.removeEventListener('storage', onStorageValueChnage);
};
```

}, []);

Comment: Of course it is, since the storage changes for ALL tabs. What's the question?

Comment: Maybe something to do with [the Note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event).

Comment: The storage event of the Window interface fires when a storage area (localStorage or sessionStorage) has been modified in the context of another document.

Comment: And now you are the getting the event fired in all tabs @SwaroopBabaleshwar?

Comment: sometimes al tabs and sometimes all other tabs except the current tab where i am in.